# HTTP client, idle timeout

Tags: go

How to make idle timeout in Go HTTP client?

Idle timeout means timeout on calling Read/Write methods of Conn interface from HTTP client internals. It can be useful when client downloads file and in some moment downloading fails because read timeout reached.

Comment: Some relevant links: http://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and and https://gobyexample.com/timeouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own `net.Dialer`, that returns a `net.Conn` which sets the appropriate read and write deadlines.

The `Conn` would look something like this:

```
// Conn wraps a net.Conn, and sets a deadline for every read
// and write operation.
type Conn struct {
    net.Conn
    ReadTimeout  time.Duration
    WriteTimeout time.Duration
}

func (c *Conn) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    err := c.Conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(c.ReadTimeout))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return c.Conn.Read(b)
}

func (c *Conn) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    err := c.Conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(c.WriteTimeout))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return c.Conn.Write(b)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand, what to do.